# RPi Zero W kernel shoots messages

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, kernel, raspbian-lite

I want to update my RPi 0 and i can't because the kernel is writing Messages with hex code that it failed but i can't fix that or even now whats going on.

only using "sudo apt-get update"
https://pastebin.com/FaAyLKgL

The first time it occurred was when i wanted to install owncloud and unzip the owncloud.tar.bz2 file. somehow it worked after dozens of hours but after I installed it and it was ready i uploaded something to the owncloud and it spitted these kernel messages in the console. I deleted everything and thought: Okay so RPi 0 can't handle owncloud so i deleted it. Now i bought an Oled Display and want to connect the RPi0 to it and followed this tutorial but... These kernel messages are coming again.

https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/ssd1306-oled-display-with-raspberry-pi

Comment: I suggest you start again from scratch.  I mean write a fresh image to the SD card.  Until you are confident in what you are doing I suggest you only install packages from the official distributions.

Comment: look again, not all of the messages are in hex

Comment: And when i want to write Noobs on it. and install any package/image like Raspbian. It freezes at some point and is impossible with Noobs. The only images are archlinux and raspbian lite. The Desktop version somehow bugs. even after 5 reinstalls its impossible to do something there except being teleported back to enter the password again and again.